# What is this the <%$ syntax in ASP.net about?

Tags: asp.net

For the first time I have come across this asp.net syntax:

`<%$ AppSettings:ValueFromConfig %>`

OR

`<% $AppSettings:ValueX %>`

What is this about? It's definitely not application level code because the dollar would have caused an issue. This appears in ascx and/or aspx front end pages.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following:

> The basic syntax of an ASP.NET expression is the following:
>
> `<%$ expressionPrefix: expressionValue %>`
>
> The dollar sign ($) indicates to ASP.NET that an expression follows.
>   The expression prefix defines the type of expression, such as
>   AppSettings, ConnectionStrings, or Resources. Following the colon (:)
>   is the actual expression value that ASP.NET will resolve.
>
> Expression syntax is not bound to any specific .NET language. You can
>   use the same expression syntax whether you use Visual Basic, C#, or
>   any other programming language in your ASP.NET pages.

~ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx

This is one of the hardest questions to search for as most search engines ignore the $ sign in the question.

See also:

- Introduction to ASP.NET inline expressions in the .NET Framework: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112